# Accessing a JavaScript / jQuery Instance only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I have a jQuery function which is called on several events (button click, change etc.)

This function is called in the documentReadyFunction and is feeded with start values..

everytime I call this function, parameters will be passed to the function.

My problem is: I don't want to create a new Object each time I call the function, because if I set a variable which decides if a part of the function is beeing executed or not, will be always overwritten..

What do I have to do, to access the first created instance instead of creating always a new one with every function call..

Down below is a simplyfied version of my function.. Maybe you understand my problem better then.

```js
$.fn.doSomething = function(param1) {
  var localParam = param1;
  var amIcalledMoreThanOnce = parseInt(0, 10);

  if (param1 == 1) {
    amIcalledMoreThanOnce = amIcalledMoreThanOnce + 1;

    if (amIcalledMoreThanOnce == 1) {
      $('#run').val(amIcalledMoreThanOnce);
      // fill form fields with URL parameters
      // This shall be executed only once after getting the URL vals
    } else {
      // set the localParam to 0 to exit this loop and reach the outter else.. 
      localParam = 0;
      $.fn.doSomething(localParam);
    }
  } else {
    $('#run').val(amIcalledMoreThanOnce);
    // use the User Input Data not the URL Params
  }
};

$.fn.doSomething(1);
$.fn.doSomething(1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="run">
```

Comment: I don't see any objects being created.

Comment: `myObject = myObject || {}`

Comment: Seems like you oversimplified this and provided a description that is too vague. Hard to make any sense out of what your problem is

Comment: There is no reason to define a method on jQuery prototype using `$.fn.method` if it is to not call it on jq object. And like said, really hard to understand the logic behind your posted code

Comment: Ok.. the story behind is.. I have a javascript which sends data via post to a php site.. the php returns a json string. I use these contents to fill form fields on my site. Now I have to build in a function to fill the form fields also with url parameters. It's a configurator for an online shop. If the customer already ordered an article, he can use the link to feed the configurator with his previous data (meassurements etc.). Now the configurator has to decide if the user is using a article-link or not. If the data will be used to fill out the form. If not, a empty configurator is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this pattern:

```
var nameOfYourFunction = (function() {

    var initializedOnlyOnce = {};

    return function() {
        //use initializedOnlyOnce here.
    }

})();
```

here what you see is; you create and run a function immediately when the code is run. The outer function immediately returns the inner function and it's assigned to nameOfYourFunction. Then you can use the nameOfYourFunction(); just as any other function. However any varible declared in the outer function will be available to the nameOfYourFunction() and initializedOnlyOnce will never be initialized again.